# Http request from blazor component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to make an http request in my blazor component to my API and I'm running into some issues, also I'm new to C#. I'm using Core 3.1.

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddHttpClient<MyHttpClient>(c => c.BaseAddress = Configuration["ServerUri"]);
```

Services folder / MyHttpClient.cs:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace My.Namespace
{
    public class MyHttpClient
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;
        private string responseString = null;

        public MyHttpClient(HttpClient client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }

        public async Task<string> HttpGets(string requestUri)
        {
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                    response = await _client.GetAsync(requestUri);
                    responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }

            return responseString;
        }
    }
}
```

Component.razor:

```
@using Services

@code {
    public IEnumerable<MyType> Data;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Data = await MyHttpClient.HttpGets("/api/getdata"); // I want to do something like this
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'

Also does this make sense or is there a better way to handle my http request? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You register the new Client but you still have to inject it:

```
@using Services
@inject MyHttpClient MyHttpClient

@code {
  ...
}
```

> ... or is there a better way to handle my http request?

Your class only adds some errorhandling and I don't see how you make it go from `string` to `IEnumerable<MyType>`.

Consider using a MyTypeService class where you use the original HttpClient directly.